# Integrating Grafana in to angularjs application with auto login and get user specific dashboard?

Tags: integration, grafana

I want to integrate grafana into my angularjs web application for monitoring purpose. I want something through which I can redirect to grafana dashboard with credentials by surpassing the grafana login page , means direct dashboard page should be displayed of logged in user of grafana. Session management should be there like dashboard data should be user specific. Please provide details to achieve this, thanks

Comment: [Automatic Authentication using Grafana API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389522/automatic-authentication-using-grafana-api)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use something like grafana auth proxy with a 3rd party authentication service or your own service.

You can load the dashboard by embedding an iframe

```
http://grafana-reverse-proxy/dashboard/db/{{dashboard}}?orgId=abc
```

Note: The url points to the reverse proxy which will authenticate your user which you pass from your angularjs app.

Alternatively if you want roles to assigned to your users, you can integrate ldap and map roles to users.

Same can be achieved with generic oauth if you have a auth service.